# question with while loop condition compare string

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm trying to get the following code to work. I want it to be so that if the input of the person's name is not an "x", I want it to skip the loop and end. If not, I want it to loop. I thought the condition would be something like the following:

```
void printProfile()
{
        //make a "cookie" or OBJECT
    HealthProfile user;
    //get name, age, weight, height info
    string personName = " ";
    int yrs;
    double weight, feetHeight, inchesHeight;

    //while the input isn't an x, keep going. if x is inputted, skip the while loop
    while(personName != "x")
    {
        //prompt name
        cout << "Enter name or X to quit: ";
        getline(cin, personName);
        //prompt age
        cout << "Your age: ";
        cin >> yrs;
        //prompt weight
        cout << "Your weight: ";
        cin >> weight;
        //prompt height feet
        cout << "Your height - feet: ";
        cin >> feetHeight;
        //prompt height inches
        cout << "Your height - inches: ";
        cin >> inchesHeight;

        user.setName(personName);
        user.setAge(yrs);
        user.setWeight(weight);
        user.setHeight(feetHeight, inchesHeight);

        cout << "Health Profile for " << user.getName() << endl;
        cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << "BMI: " << user.getBMI() << endl;
        cout << "BMI Category: " << user.getCategory() << endl;
        cout << "Max heart rate: " << user.getMaxHR() << endl;
    }
}
```

but it actually runs the whole loop through one last time on input of "x" and then ends the program. How do I make it so that putting in x exits the program?

Comment: If you write `while (personName != "x") { ... }` it runs the loop as long as `personName != "x"`  If you want it to only run the loop while `personName == "x"` then you should write `while (personName == "x") { ... }`

Comment: the condition set inside a `while` is the condition to ENTER the brackets, its easier to think about it as an `if` statement if that statement is satisfied the code inside the brackets will run and at the end it goes to the beginning to check if that condition is still `true`

Comment: yea i'm trying to get it so that as long as personName != x, then we run the loop through but if it does equal x then it exits

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please.  The bug is probably due to some other part of your program.

Comment: made edits to show more of the code, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop condition to

```
while(true)
```

After you got the name, add a check:

```
if((personName == "x")
    break;
```

Comment: is there a way to not use the break?

Comment: @ASMstudent sure, ask for the name once before the loop, and then at the end of it; then you can keep your “while”